# Вічна(я) пам'ять

Tags: словосполучення

"Вічная пам'ять" або "вічна пам'ять"

Коли вживається перший варіант?

Comment: Коли архаьично чи поетично, але запитаньа вельми низького ґатунку, спробуьте спершу навести роздуми або обґрунтуьте, чому досі маьете сумніві, а то виходить питанье шитбу: _шчо красше: **б** чи **г**_?

Comment: _Вічная_ — це **нестягнена** форма прикметника, уже було запитання [«Нестягнені форми прикметників є нормативними в українській мові?»](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/4265).

Answer (score 2):

Вживаємо виразу *вічная памʼять* коли важлива художня чи стара риса.

Ваше запитанє вельми низького ґатунку, але так трапило ся, шчо я зрозумів відки цє запитанє — від назви окремки [*Vichnaya Pamyat*](https://www.hbo.com/schedule?focusId=812854) короткої шерегстрічки [*Chernobyl*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB)) (хоча варто *Chornobyl*). Окремка шче не виьшла, тому поки не можна судити напевно, але тут скоріш має ся [піснӧсьпів східного обряду](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC'%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C) для врочистого поминаня покіьних. Зазвичаь тричі співають за наступною схемою:

- диякон *У блаженнім успінні вічний спокій подай Господи, усопшим рабам твоїм, ім'ярек: і сотворимо їм вічную пам'ять*
- хор *Вічная пам'ять! Вічная пам'ять! Вічная пам'ять!*